# Conditional backfill of Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     DATE       ID      STATUS
0  2014-01-01   1  INPROGRESS
1  2013-03-01   1       ENDED
2  2015-05-01   2  INPROGRESS
3  2012-05-01   1     STARTED
4  2011-05-01   2     STARTED
5  2011-03-01   3     STARTED
6  2011-04-01   3       ENDED
7  2011-06-01   3  INPROGRESS
8  2011-09-01   3     STARTED
```

here the code to build it:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE", "ID", "STATUS"])
>>> df1["DATE"] = ['2014-01-01', '2013-03-01', '2015-05-01', '2012-05-01', '2011-05-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01', '2011-06-01', '2011-09-01']
>>> df1["ID"] = [1,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,3]
>>> df1["STATUS"] = ['INPROGRESS', 'ENDED', 'INPROGRESS', 'STARTED', 'STARTED', 'STARTED','ENDED', 'INPROGRESS', 'STARTED']
```

for each ID group the status column represents a task that can be:

STARTED, INPROGRESS or ENDED

in this precise time order (STARTED should not came after ENDED etc..).

By grouping by ID and sorting by date I get for ID 3:

```
df1.sort_values('DATE')[df1['ID']==3]

     DATE        ID      STATUS
 5  2011-03-01   3     STARTED
 6  2011-04-01   3       ENDED
 7  2011-06-01   3  INPROGRESS
 8  2011-09-01   3     STARTED
```

No I would need to "FIX" the status column to follow the order defined above based on the **last** status. For the ID 3 the last status is started so everything should be backfilled to the started status as follow:

```
     DATE        ID      STATUS
 5  2011-03-01   3     STARTED
 6  2011-04-01   3     STARTED
 7  2011-06-01   3     STARTED
 8  2011-09-01   3     STARTED
```

For ID 1:

```
df1.sort_values('DATE')[df1['ID']==1]
     DATE  ID      STATUS
3  2012-05-01   1     STARTED
1  2013-03-01   1       ENDED
0  2014-01-01   1  INPROGRESS
```

I would end up having the last two status INPROGRESS and leave the first as STARTED like:

```
df1.sort_values('DATE')[df1['ID']==1]
     DATE  ID      STATUS
3  2012-05-01   1     STARTED
1  2013-03-01   1  INPROGRESS
0  2014-01-01   1  INPROGRESS
```

ID 2 has the correct order.

Any idea how can I do that with pandas ? 
I am trying by grouping by ID and I am thinking about backfill based on the last status but I don't know how I could stop backfilling at the right moment.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An classic way is to forget your statuses are labels: instead see them as strictly increasing numbers, like started 1, in progress 2 and ended 3. With such a column you can now check the monotony of these numbers per group, then backfill until you see a disruption in monotony.

Prepare your dataframe:

```
keymapping = {'STARTED':0, 'INPROGRESS':1, 'ENDED':2}
df['STATUS_ID'] = df.STATUS.map(keymapping)
df.set_index(['ID', 'DATE'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Now, group by ID and use `transform` to get the last value of each group spread across the entire index, so that you can assign it to your dataframe as a new column:

```
df['STATUS_LAST'] = df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).STATUS_ID.transform('last')

df
Out[63]: 
                   STATUS  STATUS_ID  STATUS_LAST
ID DATE                                          
1  2012-05-01     STARTED          0            1
   2013-03-01       ENDED          2            1
   2014-01-01  INPROGRESS          1            1
2  2011-05-01     STARTED          0            1
   2015-05-01  INPROGRESS          1            1
3  2011-03-01     STARTED          0            0
   2011-04-01       ENDED          2            0
   2011-06-01  INPROGRESS          1            0
   2011-09-01     STARTED          0            0
```

Finally, apply the backfilling by using the increasing monotony of `STATUS_ID` against last, i.e. each value of `STATUS_ID` is valid when if is lower than or equal to `STATUS_LAST`:

```
df.STATUS_ID = df.STATUS_ID.where(df.STATUS_ID <= df.STATUS_LAST, df.STATUS_LAST)
df.STATUS_ID
Out[65]: 
ID  DATE      
1   2012-05-01    0
    2013-03-01    1
    2014-01-01    1
2   2011-05-01    0
    2015-05-01    1
3   2011-03-01    0
    2011-04-01    0
    2011-06-01    0
    2011-09-01    0
```

Reverse map it to the labels and assign it to `STATUS`:

```
df.STATUS_ID.map({v:k for k,v in keymapping.items()})
Out[66]: 
ID  DATE      
1   2012-05-01       STARTED
    2013-03-01    INPROGRESS
    2014-01-01    INPROGRESS
2   2011-05-01       STARTED
    2015-05-01    INPROGRESS
3   2011-03-01       STARTED
    2011-04-01       STARTED
    2011-06-01       STARTED
    2011-09-01       STARTED
Name: STATUS_ID, dtype: object
```