# Conditional backfill of Pandas columns, another variation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

| Track | FGrating | HorseId | Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Happy Valley grass | 97 | 22609 |  |
| Happy Valley grass | 106 | 22609 | 97 |
| Happy Valley grass | 104 | 22609 | 106 |
| Happy Valley grass | 102 | 22609 | 104 |
| Happy Valley grass | 95 | 22609 | 102 |
| Sha Tin grass | 108 | 22609 |  |
| Sha Tin grass | 104 | 22609 |  |
| Happy Valley grass | 107 | 22609 | 95 |
| Sha Tin grass | 102 | 22609 |  |
| Happy Valley grass | 108 | 22609 | 107 |

I need to fill the empty cells of the rightmost column according to these two rules:

1. If the horse didn't race on the particular track yet (Happy Valley grass, in this example), then the value to be filled is 0;
2. Between two races at the particular track (Happy Valley grass, in this example), the value to be filled is the last FGrating on the track in question (the two consecutive rows with Sha Tin grass will get the value 95 and the third one will get 107).

The end result will be like this:

| Track | FGrating | HorseId | Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Happy Valley grass | 97 | 22609 | 0 (rule 1) |
| Happy Valley grass | 106 | 22609 | 97 |
| Happy Valley grass | 104 | 22609 | 106 |
| Happy Valley grass | 102 | 22609 | 104 |
| Happy Valley grass | 95 | 22609 | 102 |
| Sha Tin grass | 108 | 22609 | 95 (rule 2) |
| Sha Tin grass | 104 | 22609 | 95 (rule 2) |
| Happy Valley grass | 107 | 22609 | 95 |
| Sha Tin grass | 102 | 22609 | 107 (rule 2) |
| Happy Valley grass | 108 | 22609 | 107 |

I need this for every `HorseId` on the Dataframe

I tried doing a backfill then filling with 0, something like this:

```
df['Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass'] = df.groupby('HorseId')['Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass'].apply(
        lambda x: x.fillna(method='bfill').fillna(0))
```

but it backfills everything, ignoring rule 1.

Can you help me here? Doing some research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340729/conditional-backfill-of-pandas-columns), I have the feeling that it is a bit more complicated than a string of `fillna`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on the information from the comments, I'd propose something like:

```
def fill(sdf, track):
    mask = sdf['Track'].eq(track).cummax()
    if mask.any():
        first = mask[mask].index[0]
        if pd.isna(sdf.at[first, 'Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass']):
            sdf.loc[~mask, 'Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass'] = 0
            sdf.at[first, 'Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass'] = 0 
    sdf['Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass'] = (
        sdf['Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass'].fillna(method='bfill')
    )
    return sdf

track = "Sha Tin grass"
df[track] = (
    df.groupby('HorseId').apply(fill, track)['Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass']
)
```

Since the operation depends on the `track`, I've made it an argument for the `fill` function. I'd also put the result into a new column (here named after the chosen `track`) to not override the base column.

Variation, which I like better (using numerical access):

```
def fill(sdf, track):
    col = sdf.columns.to_list().index('Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass')
    mask = sdf['Track'].eq(track)
    if mask.any():
        first = mask.values.argmax()
        if pd.isna(sdf.iat[first, col]):
            sdf.iloc[:first + 1, col] = 0
    sdf.iloc[:, col] = sdf.iloc[:, col].fillna(method='bfill')
    return sdf
```

**EDIT**: Removed the first insufficient attempts, made slight adjustments to current answer, and added a variation.

Comment: It works well on the provided Dataframe, but not on another. As an example, let's take the same Dataframe, but we want to do the same on Sha Tin grass. The result is (on the rightmost column, from top to bottm): 0, 6 times 108, 104, 114, 114, 3 times 101 and 3 times blank. It should be: 6 times 0, 108, 104, 114, 114, 3 times 101 and 3 times 102. It is not necessary to have only the first row which go under rule nr. 1. There can be more of them

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Okay, but then it's unclear to me how the track selection should work: Either you provide it as another argument (code has to be adjusted then) or there is some logic to _the horse didn't race on the particular track yet_ that I couldn't find in the question?

Comment: There are three tracks: `Sha Tin grass`, `Happy Valley grass` and `Sha Tin Dirt`. I am trying to do this for every track. In the question I provided a sample Dataframe, thinking that it should be enough for an answer. If you need more data, I'll edit the question.

PS: For `Sha Tin grass`, for the provided dataframe, the result should be: 6 times 0, 108, 108, 104, 102. Sorry.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Thanks, now I understand, will look into it.